# Sqlite to Postgres (Heroku) Date/Time

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I am getting an error when pushing a Rails 3 app into production on Heroku (postgres) while locally (sqlite) the code works fine - I took at look at the Postgres manual to no avail:

**My Code:**

> (strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s',
>   posts.created_at)

**Error:**

> LINE 1: SELECT posts.*,
>   ((strftime('%s','now') -...
> HINT:  No
>   function matches the given name and
>   argument types. You might need to add
>   explicit type casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you don't have a function strftime. To compute the number of seconds between to dates you can use:

```
SELECT extract(epoch from now() - posts.created_at);
```

It's also important to remark that in PostgreSQL you have the interval data type, so if you just subtract (now() - posts.created_at) it will return a nice interval type for you, which can be easily formated with to_char.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is that function supposed to do?

To format a date or timestamp column use [to_char()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

To calculate the difference in days between two dates simply use: `now() - posts.created_at` (assuming created_at is a column of type `date`)

If `created_at` is not a `date` column (which would be a big mistake) you need to use to_date() to convert a string to a date.

Comment: This is a Rails app so `created_at` should be a `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

Between [formatting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-formatting.html) and postgres' date/time [types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-datetime.html) and [functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html) you need to work out the exact syntax.

If you are aiming for portability between sqlite and postgres a possible solution is to define strftime function in postgres.