# calculate time between two datetime - ActiveRecord/SQL/Heroku

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, heroku

Using Rails ActiveRecord, am wanting to calculate the time between two datetime fields within the same row. The difference between the two datetimes could be seconds through to hours, and could span mid-night. A number of seconds representing the difference would be dandy.

Am using both sqlite and postgress.

Playing with sqlite, the following just gives 0 for the calculation. (both "solved_at" and "started_at" are type "datetime", and "solved_at" is later than "started_at")

```
SELECT  (datetime(solved_at) - datetime(started_at)) FROM "schedules";
```

Comment: I hate the SEO phrases snippet so, so very much. Moderation should pick up duplicates by the users that can't search just fine.

Comment: likely that ActiveRecord doesn't do this, and that different SQL is needed for Sqlite3 and Postgres. So will have logic that checks whether Rails.env.development? (Sqlite3) or Rails.env.production? (Heroku) and specific SQL accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
dur_sql = "strftime('%s',solved_at) - strftime('%s',started_at)" unless Rails.env.production? # sqlite in dev and test modes    
dur_sql = "extract( epoch from solved_at - started_at)" if Rails.env.production? # heroku with postgres

select_clause = "count(*) as count, env, case_type, date(started_at) as started_at_date, " + "AVG(#{dur_sql}) as avg_dur, MIN(#{dur_sql}) as min_dur, MAX(#{dur_sql}) as max_dur"

group_clause = "env, case_type, date(started_at)"

where_clause = ...
grouped_stuff = Schedule.select( select_clause ).where( where_clause ).group( group_clause )
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is not performance effective but it should give you expected result.

```
Schedule.all.collect{|s| s.solved_at - s.started_at}
```

Recommended approach is to do it in query itself at db level.

Answer (score 1):

in Ruby, `schedule.solved_at - schedule.started_at` will return the distance of time in seconds

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can get the time difference by executing:

```
SELECT AGE(TIMESTAMP date1, TIMESTAMP date2);
```

This gives an interval, in order to transform it into seconds you execute:

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM interval)
```

Example:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM AGE(TIMESTAMP '1957-06-13 13:43:22', TIMESTAMP '1965-03-12 10:00:00'));
 date_part  
------------
 -244131398
(1 row)
```

Comment: sqlite> select AGE(solved_at, started_at) from schedules;

Error: no such function: AGE

Comment: but that got me thinking ... sqlite> SELECT strftime('%s',solved_at) - strftime('%s',started_at) from schedules;  looks like it gives right results, though not ActiveRecord per se, and may not be PostgreSQL (will check and update later)

Comment: looks like strftime is not for Postgreql: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566530/sqlite-to-postgres-heroku-date-time